# calling 2 https requests simultaneously in hubot coffescript

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /log (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    group = "test"
    incident_message = msg.match[0]
    service_key = keys[group]
    curtime = new Date().getTime()
    incident_key = "hubot/#{curtime}"
    reporter = msg.message.user.name
    query = {
      "service_key": service_key,
      "incident_key": incident_key,
      "event_type": "trigger",
      "description": "Change Log #{reporter}",
      "details": "#{incident_message}"
    }
    string_query = JSON.stringify(query)
    content_length = string_query.length
    msg
      .http("https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json")
      .headers
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Content-length": content_length
      .post(string_query) (err, res, body) ->
      result = JSON.parse(body)
      if result.status == "success"
        msg.send "Your log has been sent"
      else
        msg.send "There was an error sending your log."
    msg
      .http("https://xyz.pagerduty.com/api/v1/incidents/#{incident_key}/acknowledge")
```

I am trying to auto acknowledge an event triggered in pagerduty. The first http request takes effect. But the second http request (last line of the code) never takes effect. I have tried varipus combinations. But it does not help. I am new to coffeescript and only use it for hubot.Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't specify what HTTP action you are doing:

```
msg.http("https://xyz.pagerduty.com/api/v1/incidents/#{incident_key}/acknowledge")
```

Should end with `.get()` or `.post()`.

Also, possibly due to bad paste, your indentation if off a bit in the middle:

```
  .post(string_query) (err, res, body) ->
  result = JSON.parse(body)
  if result.status == "success"
    msg.send "Your log has been sent"
  else
    msg.send "There was an error sending your log."
```

Should be:

```
  .post(string_query) (err, res, body) ->
    result = JSON.parse(body)
    if result.status == "success"
      msg.send "Your log has been sent"
    else
      msg.send "There was an error sending your log."
```

Another thing, due to nature of NodeJS, these HTTP calls are made asynchronously, and there is a good chance that second call finishes before first one does. To avoid that, run the second request from callback of the first one:

```
msg
  .http("https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json")
  .headers
  "Content-type": "application/json",
  "Content-length": content_length
  .post(string_query) (err, res, body) ->
    result = JSON.parse(body)
    if result.status == "success"
      msg.send "Your log has been sent"
      msg
        .http("https://xyz.pagerduty.com/api/v1/incidents/#{incident_key}/acknowledge")
        .get()
    else
      msg.send "There was an error sending your log."
```

You can find some examples of Hubot HTTP requests and other scripting tricks [here](https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot/read).